# Original classic-gnome.session

Tags: 11.04, session, gnome

The question should be simple: I carelessly replaced the file `/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/classic-gnome.session` without making a backup file. The thing is that I didn't get what I needed and I need to get back the original version of this file.

Machine (laptop): 11.04 (Natty Narwhal), kernel 2.6.38-8-generic

Reading another question I found that the following contents can be a good alternative, but I don't dare to use it already:

```
[GNOME Session] 
Name=Classic GNOME
Required=windowmanager;panel;filemanager;
Required-windowmanager=gnome-wm
Required-panel=gnome-panel
Required-filemanager=nautilus
DefaultApps=gnome-settings-daemon;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a vanilla 11.04 classic-gnome.session file:

```
[GNOME Session]
Name=Classic GNOME
Required=windowmanager;panel;filemanager;
Required-windowmanager=gnome-wm
Required-panel=gnome-panel
Required-filemanager=nautilus
DefaultApps=gnome-settings-daemon;
IsRunnableHelper=/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test --compiz
FallbackSessionsID=GNOME2d
GNOME2d=2d-gnome
```

In case single system files were accidentally deleted they can always be restored from a live session. Boot from your installation CD, browse the *Files System* with Nautilus to `/etc/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/` and copy `classic-gnome.session` to your local drive.